# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un objeto de acuerdo a su key?

Tags: javascript, json

Actualmente tengo este objecto pero lo que necesito cambiar de posicion los keys

```
const json = [
      {
        correo: "ANGIE.PULIDO@SEGUROSDELESTADO.COM.CO", //la necesito de 3
        enviado: true, //la necesito de 4
        excel: true, //la necesito de 6
        fechaSolicitud: "08-10-2021", //la necesito de 1
        fechas: "[2021-07-31]",//la necesito de 7
        idCliente: 34170, //la necesito de 2
        pdf: true,  //la necesito de 5
        planes: //la necesito de 8
          "[{f:25,p:110020904148}, {f:25,p:112690000002}, {f:25,p:112690000006}, {f:25,p:112690000007}, {f:25,p:112690000019}, {f:25,p:112690000025}, {f:25,p:112690000026}, {f:25,p:112690000030}, {f:25,p:112690000037}, {f:25,p:112690000038}, {f:25,p:112690000039}, {f:25,p:112690000040}, {f:25,p:112690000041}, {f:25,p:112690000042}, {f:25,p:112690000056}, {f:25,p:112690000057}, {f:25,p:112690000058}, {f:25,p:112690000059}, {f:25,p:112690000063}, {f:25,p:112690000069}, {f:25,p:112690000076}, {f:25,p:112690000083}, {f:25,p:112690000084}, {f:25,p:112690000104}, {f:25,p:112690000105}, {f:25,p:112690000108}, {f:25,p:112690000117}, {f:25,p:112690000130}, {f:25,p:112690000131}, {f:25,p:112690000132}]"
      }
    ];
```

como puede ver lo que necesito es cambiar la posicion de el objecto cuando lo este iterando pero no se como hacerlo

le puedo mostar como tengo el codigo

```
//tengo los las keys
let keys= []
for (const i in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    //obtengo las claves
    keys = Object.keys(json[i])
  }
}
console.log(headers)
```

les comparto el codesandbox si alguien me quiere ayudar  [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-bash-l79b8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

Es una pregunta recurrente en este sitio, de diversas formas pero buscando siempre ordenar propiedades de objetos, y he encontrado esta respuesta en el SO en inglés que me parece adecuada traducir para que quede registrada en SO en español.

---

### [Respuesta traducida de SO en ingleś](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order):

El orden de iteración de los objetos sigue un determinado [conjunto de reglas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/292500) desde ES2015, pero no (siempre) sigue el orden de inserción. En pocas palabras, el orden de iteración es una combinación del orden de inserción para claves de cadenas y el orden ascendente para claves de tipo numérico:

```javascript
// Orden de las claves: 1, foo, bar
const obj = { "foo": "foo", "1": "1", "bar": "bar" }
```

Usar un array o un [objeto Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) puede ser una mejor manera de lograr esto. `Map` comparte algunas similitudes con `Object` y [garantiza que las claves se iteren en orden de inserción](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared), sin excepción:

> The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus,
> when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of
> insertion. (Note that in the ECMAScript 2015 spec objects do preserve
> creation order for string and Symbol keys, so traversal of an object
> with ie only string keys would yield keys in order of insertion)

Cuya traducción seria:

> Las claves en Map están ordenadas mientras que las claves agregadas al
> objeto no lo están. Así, al iterar sobre él, un objeto Map devuelve
> claves en orden de inserción. (Tenga en cuenta que en la
> especificación ECMAScript 2015, los objetos conservan el orden de
> creación de las claves de cadena y símbolo, por lo que el recorrido de
> un objeto con, por ejemplo, solo claves de cadena, produciría claves en
> el orden de inserción)

Como nota, el orden de las propiedades en los objetos no estaba garantizado en absoluto antes de ES2015. Definición de un objeto de [ECMAScript Tercera edición (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value,
> object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
> called a method.

Cuya traducción seria:

> 4.3.3 Objeto
>
> Un objeto es un miembro del tipo Objeto. **Es una colección desordenada
> de propiedades**, cada una de las cuales contiene un valor, objeto o
> función primitivos. Una función almacenada en una propiedad de un
> objeto se llama método.

---

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas intentando esta correcto, en querer obtener los "keys" del objeto. Ya que tienes los *keys* (que es un arreglo de strings) lo que deberias de hacer es usar el metodo [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), que en este caso como son strings, el ordenamiento seria alfabeticamente. Despues tendrias que poner en nuevo objeto los valores del objeto original en base al nuevo arreglo con los *keys* ordenados. Algo como lo siguiente:

```js
const sortObjectByKeys = obj => {
  const sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj).sort()

  let newObj = {}
  // aqui se esta tomando el _key_ en el orden que estan en el arreglo
  // sortedKeys(orden alfabetico)
  for (let key of sortedKeys) {
    newObj[key] = obj[key]
  }

  return newObj
}
```

Ahora usando el metodo [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const sortObjectByKeys = obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((newObj, key)=> {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
        return newObj;
    },{});
}
```

**Edit**: como tu `json` es un arreglo de objetos, para ordenar los objetos de un arreglo podrias usar el metodo `.map()` para obtener un nuevo arreglo con los *keys* de los objetos ya ordenados. Asi:

```js
const newArr = json.map(item => sortObjectByKeys(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejame entender, lo que intentas es ordenar los valores de un objeto en una lista, pero en el orden de los keys de este objeto que tu deseas? O por lo menos eso me da a entender. Utilizando tu ejemplo intente lo siguiente:

```
const final =[];
let order = ["fechaSolicitud", "idCliente", "correo", "enviado", "pdf", "excel", "fechas", "planes"]; //Orden en el que quieres la salida.

json.map( (entity)=> { // recorrer la lista de objetos.
    let arreglo =[];
    const keys = Object.keys(entity);
    keys.forEach((x) => { //recorrer las propiedades
    // Utilizamos findIndex() para obtener la posicion en la que se 
    // encuentra la key en order[] donde el valor actual del key es "x"
    // entonces lo insertamos en arreglo[] el valor actual de esa key en dicha posicion
      arreglo[order.findIndex(y => y == x)] = entity[x]; 
     // lo que en ejecucion se veria mas o menos asi:
     // arreglo[0] = entity["fechaSolicitud"];
     // arreglo[1] = entity["idCliente"];
     // etc.
    });
    console.log(arreglo);
    final.push(arreglo); // ponerlo dentro de otra lista para acumularlos.
});

console.log(final);
```

Lo probe con tu archivo y me dio esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo keys Ordenadas:

```
const final =[];
    let order = ["fechaSolicitud", "idCliente", "correo", "enviado", "pdf", "excel", "fechas", "planes"]; //Orden en el que quieres la salida.
    
json.map( (entity)=> {
    let arreglo ={};
    const keys = Object.keys(entity);
    keys.forEach((x) => {
      arreglo[order.findIndex(y => y == x)] = x;
    });
    console.log(arreglo);
    final.push(arreglo);
});

console.log(final);
```

Objeto Ordenado:

```
const final = [];
let order = ["fechaSolicitud", "idCliente", "correo", "enviado", "pdf", "excel", "fechas", "planes"]; //Orden en el que quieres la salida.
let obj_ordered={};
json.map((entity) => {
  let arreglo = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(entity);
  keys.forEach((x) => {
    arreglo[order.findIndex(y => y == x)] = x;
  });
  console.log(arreglo);
  arreglo.forEach(x => { obj_ordered[x] = entity[x] });
  console.log(obj_ordered);
  final.push(obj_ordered);
});
```

Es lo que buscabas?

Comment: no necesito los valores solo la keys

0: "fechaSolicitud" 
1: "idCliente"
2: "correo"
3: "enviado"
4: "pdf"
5: "excel"
6: "fechas"
7: "planes"

solo necesito ordenar son las key 
recuerda que es un **arreglo de objecto**  no es un arreglo NECESITO AYUDA CON ESTO NO SE CUANTO ME COBRAS PORQUE LO NECESITO UN EXCEL QUE YA ESTA DESCARGANDO

Comment: si solo ocupas las keys solo cambia let arreglo = {}; y arreglo[order.findIndex(y => y == x)] = x;