# Ya ordena objecto, ahora falta que ordene array de objecto

Tags: javascript, json

Como les comonento estoy haciendo una funcionalidad para ordenar array de objecto pero tengo un ejemplo con objectos solo. Ya los ordena pero lo que necesito yo es que me pueda ordenar un array de objecto les comparto el codigo.

```
const json = 
{
  correo: "ANGIE.PULIDO@SEGUROSDELESTADO.COM.CO",
  enviado: true,
  excel: true,
  fechaSolicitud: "08-10-2021",
  fechas: "[2021-07-31]",
  idCliente: 34170,
  pdf: true,
  planes:
    "[{f:25,p:110020904148}, {f:25,p:112690000002}, {f:25,p:112690000006}, {f:25,p:112690000007}, {f:25,p:112690000019}, {f:25,p:112690000025}, {f:25,p:112690000026}, {f:25,p:112690000030}, {f:25,p:112690000037}, {f:25,p:112690000038}, {f:25,p:112690000039}, {f:25,p:112690000040}, {f:25,p:112690000041}, {f:25,p:112690000042}, {f:25,p:112690000056}, {f:25,p:112690000057}, {f:25,p:112690000058}, {f:25,p:112690000059}, {f:25,p:112690000063}, {f:25,p:112690000069}, {f:25,p:112690000076}, {f:25,p:112690000083}, {f:25,p:112690000084}, {f:25,p:112690000104}, {f:25,p:112690000105}, {f:25,p:112690000108}, {f:25,p:112690000117}, {f:25,p:112690000130}, {f:25,p:112690000131}, {f:25,p:112690000132}]"
};

const order = [
  "fechaSolicitud",
  "idCliente",
  "correo",
  "enviado",
  "pdf",
  "excel",
  "fechas",
  "planes"
];

function preferredOrder(obj, order) {
  var newObject = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(order[i])) {
      newObject[order[i]] = obj[order[i]];
    }
  }
  return newObject;
}

const dato = preferredOrder(json, order);
console.log(dato);
```

LO QUE NECESITO QUE ME LEA UN ARRAY DE OBJECTO COMO ESTE:

```
 const json = [
    {
      correo: "ANGIE.PULIDO@SEGUROSDELESTADO.COM.CO",
      enviado: true,
      excel: true,
      fechaSolicitud: "08-10-2021",
      fechas: "[2021-07-31]",
      idCliente: 34170,
      pdf: true,
      planes:
        "[{f:25,p:110020904148}, {f:25,p:112690000002}, {f:25,p:112690000006}, {f:25,p:112690000007}, {f:25,p:112690000019}, {f:25,p:112690000025}, {f:25,p:112690000026}, {f:25,p:112690000030}, {f:25,p:112690000037}, {f:25,p:112690000038}, {f:25,p:112690000039}, {f:25,p:112690000040}, {f:25,p:112690000041}, {f:25,p:112690000042}, {f:25,p:112690000056}, {f:25,p:112690000057}, {f:25,p:112690000058}, {f:25,p:112690000059}, {f:25,p:112690000063}, {f:25,p:112690000069}, {f:25,p:112690000076}, {f:25,p:112690000083}, {f:25,p:112690000084}, {f:25,p:112690000104}, {f:25,p:112690000105}, {f:25,p:112690000108}, {f:25,p:112690000117}, {f:25,p:112690000130}, {f:25,p:112690000131}, {f:25,p:112690000132}]"
    }];
```

**Nota:**
Ya ordena objecto pero todavia no ordena array de objecto necesito ayuda

Comment: Hola Fabian, esta pregunta en contexto y codigo es exactamente igual a esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/511812/cómo-puedo-ordenar-un-objeto-de-acuerdo-a-su-key/511819 a lo mejor de ahi puedes sacar alguna repuesta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo ordenar un objeto de acuerdo a su key?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/511812/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-ordenar-un-objeto-de-acuerdo-a-su-key)